# Как динамически создать <li> в ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular

Как сделать, чтобы каждый элемент в массиве skills был в отдельном li
т.е. сейчас так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а нужно вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
 
 
 
 
 people = [
    {name:"Aram", surname:"Hakobyan",skills:["Angular", "react",], salary:125000},
    {name:"Gago", surname:"Hakobyan",skills:["Angular", "react", "C#"] ,salary:45000},
    {name:"Narek", surname:"Hakobyan",skills:["Angular", "react",], salary:350000},
    {name:"Saqo", surname:"Hakobyan",skills:["Angular", "react",], salary:420000},
  ]
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>surname</th>
      <th>skills</th>
      <th>salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr [class.bg-success]="item.skills.length==3" *ngFor="let item of people">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.surname}}</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFOR="let skl of skills">{{item.skills}}</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>{{item.salary}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: `ngFOR` -> `ngFor`, `skills` -> `item.skills`, `item.skills` -> `skl`

Comment: @Grundy, так?  <li ngFOR -> *ngFor, skills -> item.skills, item.skills -> skl>{{skl.skills}}</li>

Comment: нет, не так...!

Comment: @Grundy, я только сегодня начал изучать ангулар, прошу попроще и по подробнее, если можно, ngFOR это обычный цикл  for?

Comment: нет такого атрибута. почему-то для tr ты правильно написал, а для li нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно цикл прогнать по массиву item.skills:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>surname</th>
      <th>skills</th>
      <th>salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr [class.bg-success]="item.skills.length==3" *ngFor="let item of people">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.surname}}</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let skill of item.skills">{{skill}}</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>{{item.salary}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```